# Posting form to an aspx page in another application

Tags: asp.net

I need to submit the form to another web application.

I have hosted 2 websites in my IIS. In website1 I have a page "Register.aspx" and I set PostBackUrl for the submit button to a page(Receiver.aspx) in website2. But I couldn't get the posted values in Receiver.aspx. If I set the PostBack url to a page which is in website1, I could get the posted values using Request.Form["tbUserName"]. Please suggest me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425829/is-it-possible-to-do-a-cross-page-post-to-an-asp-net-from-a-static-html-form

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242447/asp-net-cross-domain-form-posting

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause. The problem is I set Cookieless="true" in website2, if I set it to UseCookies it works fine.