# Posting form to an aspx page in another application when cookieless set to true

Tags: asp.net, session-cookies

I need to submit the form to another web application.

I have hosted 2 websites in my `IIS`. In website1 I have a page ***"Register.aspx"*** and I set `PostBackUrl` for the submit button to a page(***Receiver.aspx***) in website2. But I couldn't get the posted values in Receiver.aspx.

If I set the PostBack url to a page which is in website1, I could get the posted values using `Request.Form["tbUserName"]`. Please suggest me.

If I change the `cookieless="UseCookies"` it works fine.

Comment: Why not get them using the `Request.Form["tbUserName"]` and move on ? There is a validation check that understand that the parameters are coming from different site and not let him pass. You need to make your custom hash check of this parameters to avoid possible attack.

Comment: Why not update your original question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500668/posting-form-to-an-aspx-page-in-another-application? Rather than creating a new one?